# How to do color parsing in A-Frame to find the amount of r/g/b from a color string?

Tags: aframe

If I'm trying to find the amount of green or red, etc. Should I just do string parsing against this:

`document.getElementById("targetElement").getAttribute("material").color`

The output is something like `"rgb(0,0,0)"` so i could use regular expression matching to find the green for example. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `THREE.Color` utilities https://threejs.org/docs/api/math/Color.html

`THREE.Color('rgb(10, 20, 30)').r  // 10`

Answer (score 0):

Try that one:

```
var greenElements = document.querySelectorAll("*").filter(function () { 
    return this.getAttribute("material") == 'rgb(0,255,0)' 
});
console.log(greenElements.length);
```

You can change selector if you know more about elements, which you want to search for. I used all matching selector, what can be 'slow' if you have a lot html to parse.